# double lock screen in Xubuntu after upgrade from 18.04 to 22.04

Tags: xfce, lock-screen

I made two successive upgrades of Xubuntu: from 18.04 to 20.04 and just after from 20.04 to  22.04. The second step had some failures due to root partition becoming full, but terminated.

I now have two consecutive lock screens when waking up from sleep, but the second lock screen does not allow any password to be entered (the field does not react, only the buttons do).

So in this situation, I have to launch a tty with Ctrl-Alt-F1 and kill the existing locked session.

See the two lock screens below (slightly different). I believe I have to different programs activated for locking, maybe one that remained from the unfinished upgrade...?

[image: First lock screen, can be unlocked]

[image: Second lock screen, password cannot be entered. The yellow banner states "password:"]

The bug only occurs when resuming from sleep, not when just locking the screen.

I tried to just lock the screen with various methods, and they give one or the other type of screen:

1. First lock screen with `light-locker-command -l` or `dm-tool lock`;
2. second lock screen with desktop button or `xflock4` or shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+L`. However, it can be unlocked.

`gnome-screensaver` is not installed.

Any solution? Are there old config files to clean? Programs to uninstall?